# array, getting title and data of top levels

Tags: php, arrays

I currently have an issue with a block of code where a simple change gives me one or the other attribute I'm looking for but not both. I can get the title or the value of the first three levels in this array but not both.

This:

```
array_walk($promo, function ($e) use (&$results) {

    $results['ID']['name']['type'][] = [
       'ATT' => $e['ATT'],
       'ATT2' => $e['ATT2'],
       'ATV' => $e['ATV']
    ];
});
```

This gives structure with titles like:

```
ID
name
type: array(
              123,
              abc,
              blue
            )
```

```
array_walk($promo, function ($e) use (&$results) {

    $ID = &$e['ID'];
    $name = &$e['name'];
    $type = &$e['type'];

    $results[$ID][$name][$type][] = [
      'ATT' => $e['ATT'],
      'ATT2' => $e['ATT2'],
      'ATV' => $e['ATV']
    ];
});
```

This gives structure with data but no titles

```
ID:26
NewList
Task_list: array(
                  123,
                  abc,
                  blue
                )
```

How can I refactor this to give me a list with the first three levels having title and data like so:

```
ID:26
name:NewList
type:Task_list: array(
                       123,
                       abc,
                       blue
                    )
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, can't you just prepend the "titles"? `$results["ID:" . $ID]["name:" . $name]["type:" . $type]`

Comment: @TomN. Show structure of php array  you want as result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify the `array_walk` like this :

```
array_walk($promo, function ($e) use (&$results) {

    $ID = &$e['ID'];
    $name = &$e['name'];
    $type = &$e['type'];

    $results['ID'][$ID]['name'][$name]['type'][$type][] = [
        'ATT' => $e['ATT'],
        'ATT2' => $e['ATT2'],
        'ATV' => $e['ATV']
    ];
});
```

Comment: This does add three new levels though, is there a way for the title and value to be the same level?